# Send a message to Kerberized Kafka. from kafka template (spring-kafka) version 1.15 (not using Spring boot)

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

[Using this](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/) kafka integration project  version 1.15 due to compatible issues.How to use send message to Kerberized kafka ,we are not using spring boot .how to set the properties to send the message to kafka?i tried to look for the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/) but couldnt find properties related to kerberos in ProducerConfig.

Answer (score 1):

See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl).

Set the `sasl.jaas.config` property as described there:

```
sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
    useKeyTab=true \
    storeKey=true  \
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab" \
    principal="kafka-client-1@EXAMPLE.COM";
```

and also

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT (or SASL_SSL)
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell for the instant reply . If im setting the properties like                                                                        
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(); props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);
  
  How do i set sasl.jaas.config for ProducerConfig

Comment: The constants for SASL configuration are in the class `SaslConfigs`, so `put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have consumed messages from **kerberozied kafka** (HDP cluster). So I am sharing my thoughts . It might help.

I've constructed my consumer properties as

```
    Map<String, Object> consumerConf = new HashMap<>();
    consumerConf.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "hdp.master:6667"); 
    consumerConf.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerConf.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerConf.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grp12");
    consumerConf.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
```

So you could add `consumerConf.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");` in your producer config.

Again need to set system properties

```
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "Path to krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "path to kafka-jaas.conf");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
```

The port no used here is 6667 since I am using kafka in our Horton works platform.